# Forcing UTF-8, but just for regexec()

Tags: c, regex, utf-8, locale, setlocale

My C program reads & writes data exclusively in UTF-8. It also uses the POSIX regex functions. I want these functions, in particular `regexec(3)`, *always* to match UTF-8 text so that `[:alpha:]` will match alphabetic characters *including* those in UTF-8, e.g., `'é'` (Latin small letter 'e' with acute accent). `regexec(3)` is locale-sensitive and, if the current locale is indeed UTF-8, [this works the way I want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728601/99089)).

However, I've also read that [forcing UTF-8 for an entire program is the wrong thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36188053/99089). (Among other things, I assume system-generated errors will not be in the user's preferred locale.)

So what about if I force UTF-8 *only* for the call to `regexec(3)` and then put it back the way it was, e.g., given this:

```
void setlocale_utf8( void ) {
  if ( !setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8" ) && !setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "UTF8" ) ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "setlocale() failed\n" );
    // do something
  }
}
```

do this:

```
setlocale_utf8();
int err_code = regexec( re, utf8_str_to_match, re->re_nsub + 1, match, 0 );
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "" ); // put locale back to the user's preferred locale
```

Is this an OK way to ensure `regexec(3)` is always matching using UTF-8? Is there a better way?

Comment: Note: perhaps it is better, when done, to change the locale to the _previous_ setting (put it back the way it was), rather than the user's preferred locale

Comment: @chux If I never set the locale at all, then the previous setting will be the "C" locale since, according to the setlocale(3) man page: "By default, C programs start in the "C" locale."

Comment: True, but this function could simply operate without that  condition: "prior code never set the locale at all"  to operate correctly.  It simple needs to set the locale, do its operations and then _restore_.  You expressed concern about "forcing UTF8 for an entire program".  By restoring, rather than setting to default, code avoids "forcing an entire program to not elsewhere change locale".

Comment: @chux: OK, if I restore, _then_ is this an OK thing to do to solve my problem?