# GnuPlot on Windows "Bad data on line 1" (edit: PowerShell encoding)

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

## Context:

Data produced by complied C code can't be read by GnuPlot (on a Windows 10 pc).

**EDIT:** *The actual problem was character encoding enforced by the environment of the Windows PowerShell.*

## Details:

Here's my (*vastly* simplified for testing) data file "data1"

```
0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00
5.0000e-01 2.5000e-01
```

This is produced by

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    double x=0.0 , y=0.0;
    printf("%.4e %.4e\n",x,y);
    x=0.5; y=x*x;
    printf("%.4e %.4e\n",x,y);
}
```

compiled on Visual Studio Code 1.84.2 (using the MSYS2 version 12.2.0 of gcc) into an executable I call "SPAM".  In the Windows power shell, in that directory, I call `.\SPAM > data1`.

**EDIT:** *The culprit is the Windows PowerShell which, through the redirect character >, encodes the output as UTF-16 LE BOM.*

Using GnuPlot 5.4 (patchlevel 8) gets me this trouble:

```
gnuplot> plot 'data1'
              ^
         Bad data on line 1 of file data1
```

## Attempts:

Typing those data in directly using `plot '-'` works fine.
Viewing the data file with Notepad++ shows no hidden or special characters.
Copy-pasting the contents of the data file into a new file solves the problem!
But I can *not* be in the business of duplicating all my (actually *huge*) datafiles.

## Question:

0. What is hidden in the datafile that GnuPlot does not like?
1. Can I solve this through changing settings/flags in GnuPlot?
2. Is there something wrong with my installation / build of VSC & gcc that's producing "weird" files?

**EDIT:** *The actual problem was none of those things -- it was the encoding enforced by the Windows PowerShell.*

Comment: What do you get if you type `pwd`? And where is your file `data1` located?

Comment: The current working directory is correct. The copy i made that GnuPlot *could* read is in the same directory.

Comment: Please confirm that line endings are as you expect. With `msys2` cmd-line, you should be able to `cat -vet data1`. If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, the somehow your `\n` is getting converted to`\r\n` (old DOS used to do this (I think)). Assuming `^M$` line-endings, try `dos2unix data1` (and test again with `cat -vet...` . If now `^M$`, then maybe becuase you're on windows, gnuplot is expecting `\r\n` endings, so add them in your code. Super good [mcve] you have provided! Keep posting and Good luck!

Comment: You may need a hexadecimal editor to see something weird at the beginning of the file. Most text editors will hide control characters and such.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters

Comment: @shellter : Here's what `cat -vet data1` returned:
"
M-^?M-~0^@.^@0^@0^@0^@0^@e^@+^@0^@0^@ ^@0^@.^@0^@0^@0^@0^@e^@+^@0^@0^@^M^@$
^@5^@.^@0^@0^@0^@0^@e^@-^@0^@1^@ ^@2^@.^@5^@0^@0^@0^@e^@-^@0^@1^@^M^@$
^@
"
What the heck is that in front of the first "0"?!?

Comment: Looks like the output from your program might be unicode. The copy and paste probably converted to ASCII by default

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171832/converting-a-utf-8-file-to-ascii-best-effort

Comment: I confirmed that a simple `gcc -o SPAM SPAM.c` works as expected in the WSL environment. First line = `0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00` And `cat -vet data1` works with only `$` as a line ending. Sorry beyond my time-scope to figure this out. Maybe run your code under Windows SusSystem for Linux (WSL) instead?  Or add a `c` tag to your Q, and move the "evidence" into the body of your question. Good luck.

Comment: I will probably have a chance to have another go at this problem on the weekend, and will update / accept answer then.  But the problem i see now is that my original ask and title has very little to do with the actual underlying problem: character encoding defaults in the Windows PowerShell.  Should i / can i edit and update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Windows 10, Powershell produces an UTF-16 encoded data1 file with a size of 94 bytes.

The "normal" command shell `cmd.exe` produces ASCII text with a size of 46 bytes.

Therefore I would suggest to use `cmd.exe` instead of Powershell to run the command `.\SPAM > data1`. Or to write a batch scripts which runs this command, the batch script can be run from Powershell.

**Update:**

According to [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/961769) you can also run this command from Powershell:

`.\SPAM | Out-File -Encoding ascii data1`

If you want a deeper understanding, you might want to search for something like "printf powershell produces UTF-16".

Comment: Interesting info. I don't know C, but isn't there an option to force UTF-8 output within the C-program, independent of Powershell or `cmd.exe`? And converting the UTF-16 output with an additional program to UTF-8 or ANSI, like helper's suggestion might certainly work, but I wouldn't consider this as a preferred solution. About forcing UTF-8, there is a discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36184019/7295599

Comment: @theozh The C program prints ASCII/UTF-8. The problem is in Powershell which changes the output encoding. After your comment I searched for `printf powershell produces utf-16`, this seems to be quite common. I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this might be the solution, but the comment of @helper might be a hint. Newer versions of gnuplot (you have 5.4.8) can definitely read ANSI and UTF-8 encoded text files, but not all variants of them.

I can reproduce your error message when I convert the encoding of the file in Notepadd++, e.g. from UTF-8 to UTF-8-BOM. Right mouse click on the encoding in the status line.

[image]

So, what does your Notepad++ show on the right side of the status line for your file as encoding?

In case your C-Code produces UTF-8-BOM or UTF-16 or some others by default, you need to change it in your C-program.

Comment: "data1" is encoded with "UTF-16 LE BOM"  :/

Comment: @Rrr ok, then you should find a way to create UTF-8 (or ANSI) output directly from your C-code. See maybe maij's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The post I listed:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171832/converting-a-utf-8-file-to-ascii-best-effort

suggests piping your data through iconv:

```
.\SPAM | iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT > data1
```

or, I think from your comment:

```
.\SPAM | iconv -c -f UTF-16LE -t ascii//TRANSLIT > data1
```

If iconv exists on your system, this should work. The -c discards characters that cannot be represented in ASCII.

I just noticed that if you pipe the data through TYPE in Win 10 it seems to convert to ASCII:

```
.\SPAM >data0
TYPE data0 >data1
```

Simple, if it works.

Comment: I'm not in a unix/linux environment, so "iconv" is not available. the second suggestion (*post*-processing) is not compatible with the workflow (hidden in details excluded from the original ask, for brevity).

Comment: Can you provide more information as to why post-processing is not compatible. I assume you are running your compiled C code in a batch file...